# Flex items not wrapping in a column direction container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to use `flex-direction:column` for a specific layout.

I usually use standard `flex-direction:row`, so I've got some problems using `column`. I don't know too much how to control it and didn't find anything useful on google.

I've got a regular `UL` list and what I want is this:

```
1 3 5 7

2 4 6
```

What I currently get is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

My current simplified code is this:

```
.ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  li{
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apply total `height` on `ul` and make it `wrap`.

Then apply `flex-basis` on `ul li` (which is height because we've applied `flex-direction: column`) to 50%. Like:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}
ul li {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* which in this case will be '50px' */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}
ul li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You need to give the flex container a defined height.

Without a fixed height on the container, the items don't know where to wrap.

You also need to add `flex-wrap: wrap`, as the initial setting on a flex container is `nowrap`.

Answer (score 4):

For the list to span multiple columns:

1. You must specify a *defined* height.
2. Set it to wrap by using `flex-wrap: wrap` (by *default* it is set to `nowrap`)

See demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 50px;
}
li {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set height on `flex-container` and also `flex-wrap: wrap`. Next you can set `flex-basis: 50%` on `flex-item` and that will give desired result.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-wrap:wrap;` on the `ul`. You dont need to set height to one value strictly but it's height should not be able to contain more than 2 at a time but should be able to contain 2.

```css
li{
  width:50px;
  list-style-type:none;
  height:50px;
  margin:5px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
ul{
  height:150px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the height of each item or how many items you will have, a more flexible solution is this:

```
ul {
  column-count: 4
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

You may also need to adjust `margin-top` of `li:first-child` if they don't align to the top.

Comment: Don't copy/paste the same answer all over, post at one place and then vote to close on the other ... [Is it ok to copy/paste myself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317609/is-it-ok-to-copy-paste-myself)

Comment: Furthermore, if you do think you know a solution that will provide the flow asked for, provide a working code snippet instead of only a CSS fragment.

Comment: I'll try to take your rebukes and downvotes to heart. In my defense, I had just spent too much time looking at SO pages about flex, when what I needed was column-count, and I was trying to help others to have a better experience.