# Material-UI: How to column wrap a list

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm currently using Material-UI to render a list of checkboxes, as done in [this example](https://v4.mui.com/components/lists/#checkbox).

The issue is that my list has about ~30 items in it, and I'm putting them all into a dialog. I want my checkbox list items to fill down to a max height (i.e. 500px), and then **the rest of the list items should wrap into a new column(s), filling the horizontal space of the dialog**.

I'm looking for something like this: [(other stackoverflow post that's asking for something similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348062/flex-items-not-wrapping-in-a-column-direction-container)

Here is my code, copied directly from the MUI Reference Docs:

```
<List className={classes.root}>
  {CHECKS.map((value: string) => {                     // (CHECKS = array of strings)
    const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${value}`;

    return (
      <ListItem
        key={value}
        role={undefined}
        dense
        button
        onClick={handleToggle(value)}
        className={classes.listItem}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Checkbox
            edge="start"
            checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
            tabIndex={-1}
            disableRipple
            inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={value} />
      </ListItem>
    );
  })}
</List>
```

But my "root" and "listItem" classes and aren't changing anything. Here is my (useless) CSS:

```
checklist: {
  display: "flex",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  flexDirection: "column",
  height: "500px",
},
item: {
  flexBasis: "50%",     // Something I saw online
},
```

Do I need to override some of the standard MUI styles or something?

(I really don't want to split my CHECKS list into 3 separate lists and flexboxes, and wrap all that in a big flexbox, etc etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`column wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items#making_things_wrap), and make sure to set `overflow` to `auto` to show the horizontal scrollbar:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexFlow: "column wrap",
    gap: "0 30px",
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    height: 300, // set the height limit to your liking
    overflow: "auto"
  },
  item: {
    width: "auto"
  }
});
```

```
<div className={classes.container}>
  {CHECKS.map((value: string) => {
    return (
      <ListItem key={value} className={classes.item}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Checkbox edge="start" disableRipple />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={value} />
      </ListItem>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This is great, thank you!! Just to note- I also had to remove the maxWidth property of the `root` class for my MUI List component, which I had copied directly from the MUI Reference docs. (It was limiting my list width to 360px, which was completely overriding your solution.)